# Javascript replace html tags with blank string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace all the `/n, <br>` and `space` in the string and replace them with `''`.

My approach is using `replace`. However, I am getting the following errors.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string
```

I know

```
console.log(text.value[langID]) would output bunch of texts.
```

but I got the error when I changed my codes to this.

```
console.log(text.value[langID].replace('/\n|<br>|\s/g', ''));
```

I am not sure what went wrong here and if my rex pattern can filter my requirements.

Can anyone gives me a hint?

Thanks so much!

Comment: BEWARE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Comment: @Diodeus He's not parsing HTML, just escaping out certain sequences.

Comment: As Claudio pointed out, the string is unexpected because you need a comma between the strings. JS doesn't expect you to just mash the strings together.

Comment: Using a tool like [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) make spotting these types of syntax errors easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You missed the comma separator for `replace` parameters. Also, as @Ingo Bürk pointed out, quotes for regex expression are not valid so you have to remove them too

```
console.log(text.value[langID].replace(/\n|<br>|\s/g,''));
```

Comment: He should also drop the quotes aorund the regular expression

Comment: Thanks, turns out it's just a simple mistake! +1